# Android: How to send back data from thread to service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Hy!

I have a service from which a start a new thread. This new thread will communicate with a TCP server using socket. What is the best way to send the data received from TCP server back to the service? Handlers or something else?

Thanks in advance,
kukukk

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since this thread was opened, but I guess people are still coming here.
I managed to achieve this using the following answer:
 [How to communicate a service with a running thread in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989099/how-to-communicate-a-service-with-a-running-thread-in-android/9014694#9014694)

Good luck ya' all.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to send the data received from TCP server back to the service?

Make the thread be an inner class of the service, then just call a method on the service.

Comment: This is the commonly used solution and officially advised by Android developers, or it is just easier?

Comment: Won't this run the method in the new (non-UI) thread, rather than the UI thread, as the enquirer asked?