# How to communicate a service with a running thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, communication

my goal is to lunch a service that will take care for all of the application network needs.

i thought maybe to open 2 sockets for data transfer. i want the data to be handled asynchronously, so i was thinking my be i should run them in two separated threads, each for every socket, and that way the data could be streamed in two different "links" async..

so, i would appreciate two things:

1. a better overall design. maybe i completely got it all wrong..
2. can someone explain to me how can i communicate with those threds once i need to pass data      to/from them to/from the main service? as far as i learnt (OS) i need to use SIGNALS:) (just kidding..)

Comment: found a very simple and concise example here: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=5424397F3130CE7769FF47DD67742911?recipeId=921&recipeFrom=ViewTOC. as i understand its a one way communication while i`m looking for bi-directional one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can say i finally got it, just before giving up. Here is a super duper extremely simple app that runs a thread inside an activity and handles a **bi-directional** communication using **two different Handlers** for each entity!

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {   
//Properties:   
    private final   String TAG = "Activity";            //Log tag
    private         MyThread mThread;                   //spawned thread 
    Bundle          myB = new Bundle();                 //used for creating the msgs
    public          Handler mHandler = new Handler(){   //handles the INcoming msgs 
        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        { 
            myB = msg.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Handler got message"+ myB.getInt("THREAD DELIVERY")); 
        } 
    }; 
//Methods:
    //--------------------------
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        mThread = new MyThread(mHandler);
        mThread.start();
        sendMsgToThread();
    }
    //-------------------------- 
    void sendMsgToThread() 
    { 
        Message msg = mThread.getHandler().obtainMessage(); 
        myB.putInt("MAIN DELIVERY", 321);
        msg.setData(myB);
        mThread.getHandler().sendMessage(msg);
    } 
}
//=========================================================================================
//=========================================================================================

public class MyThread extends Thread{   
//Properties:
    private final   String TAG = "MyThread";            //Log tag
    private         Handler outHandler;                 //handles the OUTgoing msgs 
    Bundle          myB = new Bundle();                 //used for creating the msgs
    private         Handler inHandler = new Handler(){  //handles the INcoming msgs 
        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        { 
            myB = msg.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Handler got message"+ myB.getInt("MAIN DELIVERY")); 
        } 
    }; 

//Methods:
    //--------------------------
    public void run(){
        sendMsgToMainThread();  //send to the main activity a msg
        Looper.prepare();
        Looper.loop();
        //after this line nothing happens because of the LOOP!
        Log.i(TAG, "Lost message");
    }
    //--------------------------
    public MyThread(Handler mHandler) {
        //C-tor that get a reference object to the MainActivity handler.
        //this is how we know to whom we need to connect with.
        outHandler = mHandler;
    }
    //--------------------------
    public Handler getHandler(){
        //a Get method which return the handler which This Thread is connected with.
        return inHandler;
    }
    //--------------------------    
    private void sendMsgToMainThread(){
        Message msg = outHandler.obtainMessage();   
        myB.putInt("THREAD DELIVERY", 123);
        msg.setData(myB);
        outHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
//=========================================================================================
//=========================================================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.test.namespace"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the output is:

```
01-26 06:25:40.683: I/Activity(19560): Handler got message123
01-26 06:25:40.683: I/MyThread(19560): Handler got message321
```

I figured this out while reading the offered  post by endian, [here](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html).

I hope others will find this useful. good luck:)

Comment: main problem here is that i cant send msgs to the activity in a pure async way. in this way, msgs can be lost if the thread\Activity is busy. **suggestions**?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html) is good post explaining threads and communication using handlers. Also, the same blog has a number of posts regarding various thread constructs in Android.

Another possibility is to use AsyncTasks. Find some explanation [here](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2260&title=Using%20AsyncTask%20to%20do%20background%20processing)

Comment: looks good. i`ll take a look but i`m pretty sure it covers up about everything i need. 10x! :)

Comment: well, it really helped but i`m starting to question my hole design. i`ll post another question about it.

Comment: i'm still very confused. i cant find the way to pass data async between a service and a thread.

Comment: follow first tutorial using the handler class

Comment: i did. still i dont understand how the thread can send his answer back to the main activty. it only shows how to do send a msg from main activty : mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

Comment: use the same method to send data back to activity

Comment: well, i guess i`m slow. i cant get a simple activity communicate with a simple thread. can anyone give me a full super simple example? p l e a s e :)